# What is wrong with this proof based on induction?

Tags: induction, riemann-zeta

Premise:

1. Let P(n) return the real part of the nth nontrivial root of the zeta function
2. The first several roots of the zeta function are already known

Proof:

1. Pick any integer n. For example, 1.
2. Solve for P(n)
3. Solve for P(n+1)
4. Both (2) and (3) are 1/2 as established by Alan Turing and others
5. By induction all P(n) are 1/2

QED the real part of all nontrivial roots of the riemann zeta function is 1/2

Any problems?

Comment: This is the same as a proof like "all girls have the same hair-colour". The catch is the case of two girls. Neither is $n=2$ a base case (two girls need not have the same hair colour) nor is $n=2$ a valid implication of the case $n=1$. Since two girls can have different hair-colours the step from $n=1$ to $n=2$ cannot be correct. If $n=2$ would be a valid case (Every two girls have equal hair-colours), we could in fact conclude that all girls have the same hair-colour.

Comment: But this is just a normal inductive argument. Your argument would refute any inductive argument.

Comment: No, the induction step must work from $n=1$ to $n=2$ (If we use $n=1$ as the base case), but it does not work here. In other words : For arbitary $n$ , if the claim is true for $n$, it must be true for $n+1$

Comment: I don't think you've explained why this is different from any other inductive argument other than saying "it doesn't work"

Comment: If we have a set with one element , lets say $M=${$x$}, then for all $a,b\in M$ we have $a=b$. This is because we have no choice, we can only select the element $x$. Now , assume the set is $M'=${$x,y$}. So, we need to show that for all $a,b\in M'$ we have $a=b$ only by using that $a=b$ always holds in the case $a,b\in M$. This does not work however because $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements. We have a choice now, so the situation is different. Therefore we cannot prove the case $n=2$ from the case $n=1$.

Comment: Do you think any inductive proofs are valid?

Comment: Of course, but you must be careful with the induction step!

Comment: Like which ones? I can just copy paste what you said and refute any inductive argument.

Comment: I just stated a general inductive argument of the form p(n), p(n+1)... so any argument you make refutes any inductive argument.

Comment: Give me an example of an inductive proof you think is valid.

Comment: An inductive argument is not "of the form p(n), p(n+1)" (for some n like, in your case, 1). Rather it is of the form "for **all** n, **if** p(n) **then** p(n+1)" together with a proof for the base case. So item (5) in your attempted proof is a non sequitur.  (Now I see that @5xum has already explained this, but I'll leave this comment here since you don't seem to understand his more extensive explanation.)

Comment: That's what I did

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this proof is that it isn't a proof. Step number 4 claims something that was not proven in previous steps. We don't know what $f$ is, that's the whole point.

Also, even if this "proof" was correct, this is not how a proof by induction. A proof of induction would look like:

1. Prove that the real part of $f(1)$ is $\frac12$.
2. Assume that the real part of $f(n)$ is $\frac12$.
3. Prove, from assumption $(2)$, that the real part of $f(n+1)$ is $\frac12$

---

An example of your proof, showing something very wrong:

1. Define $P(n) = n$
2. The first several values of $P(n)$ are already known

Claim: for all values $n$, the value $P(n)$ is smaller than $1000000$.

Proof:

1. Pick any integer $n$, for example $1$.
2. Solve for $P(n)$
3. Solve for $P(n+1)$
4. Both (2) and (3) are smaller than $1000000$ as $1<1000000$ and $2<1000000$.
5. By induction all $P(n)$ are smaller than $1000000$

---

An example of a good proof by induction:

Claim: For all values $n\in\mathbb N$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ is equal to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Proof:

First of all, the claim is true for $n=1$ since $$\sum_{i=1}^1 i = 1 = \frac{1\cdot(1+1)}{2}$$

Now, assume that the claim is true for $n$.

1. By assumption, $$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$
2. By definition, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i = \sum_{i=1}^n i + (n+1)$$
3. From (1) and (2), it follows that 
   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i = \sum_{i=1}^n i + (n+1) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n+1$$
4. Simplifying the expression, we get $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n+1 = \frac{n^2+n}{2} + \frac{2n+2}{2} = \frac{n^2+3n+2}{2} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$
5. From (4), it follows that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$ in other words, the claim is true for $n+1$.

So, assuming that the claim is true for $n$, we have proven (in point (5)), that the claim is true for $n+1$. We have also proven that the claim is true for $1$. This allows us to conclude that the claim is true for all values of $n$.

---

Unlike *your* proof, this valid induction proof cannot be refuted by the same arguments. It is valid for all values of $n$.

Comment: N can be any value. 1 for example. The first two n's are definitely 1/2 right? This has been confirmed many times by Alan Turing and others.

Comment: @user389973 Well, yes, the claim is true for n=1. But you have to prove it for a general value of n.

Comment: Then if I prove for n+1 isn't that a general proof

Comment: @user389973 yes, but it needs to be a GENERAL value of n. Just because it is true for 1 and 2 doesnt make it true for 85728374628374828476.

Comment: Your argument would refute any inductive argument

Comment: @user389973 if you think that you need to recheck what induction is. It is not finding ONE PARTICULAR pair n, n+1 for which the claim is true. It is taking a GENERAL value of n and showing that IF the claim is true for n, THEN it must also be true for n+1

Comment: That's what I did. Give me an example of what you are saying.

Comment: @user389973 no you didn't do that. You proved the claim for n=1 and n=2. Your proof could just as well be used to prove that all integers are smaller than 5, because this claim is true for n=1,2

Comment: Your argument could refute any inductive argument

Comment: You need to read about basic analysis and proofs. I don't want to be rude, but if you don't understand what the problem with your proof is, you have a serious lack of understanding mathematics. Take a textbook and do the exercises on induction. It takes weeks if not months to understand these things.

Comment: Why did you copy the previous comment ? What do you want to tell us with that ?

Comment: That I'm looking for another answer.

Comment: @user389973 You need to prove the statement "For all values of $n$, if $P(n)$ has the real value of $\frac12$, then $P(n+1)$ has the real value $\frac12$. You did not prove this statement.

Comment: @user389973 I edited my answer to show how your "proof" can be modified to show that all integers are smaller than $1000000$.

Comment: I just used regular proof by induction of the form p(n), p(n+1)... So your arguments refute any proof by induction.

Comment: @user389973 You are very obviously not listening to me or considering my arguments. That's fine with me. I understand why your proof is wrong. If you won't listen to my reasons, I don't really care. You are wrong, and I told you well enough why. You can google the web for any number of real inductive proofs and see how my argumet *cannot* refute them. But I get the impression you don't really want to learn anything. And that's fine by me. I just won't spend any more time on someone who refuses to learn.

Comment: Show me a proof by induction you consider valid.

Comment: No. I refuse to answer any questions until you show some effort in understanding my point

Comment: @user389973 A statement you have to prove is "For all $n\in\mathbb N$: if $P(n)$ has real part $\frac12$, then $P(n+1)$ has real part $\frac12$". Can you point to where you proved this statement?

Comment: @user389973 I also added an example of a valid proof by induction.

Comment: your "proof" can be modified to show that all integers are smaller than 10000001000000. Just read your own post.

Comment: @user389973 OK, then do it. Modify my proof and prove that all integers are smaller than 10000001000000. You can do it in comments or by editing your own answer.

Comment: You already showed it. Anything that refutes my proof refutes yours because its just a standard inductive argument.

Comment: @user389973 You keep saying that, but if you think so, please prove your statement. See, this is *mathematics*, and in mathematics, statements are worthless if they aren't proven. So, you claim that it is possible to *change* my proof such that the structure remains the same, but that it proves something ridiculous. Well, OK, that's a statement. A claim you are making. Now, it's time for you to prove it. If it can be done, then *do it*.

Comment: You keep saying things, but if you think so, please prove your statement

Comment: @user389973 I'm not the one making the claim. You are. You claim "your "proof" can be modified to show that all integers are smaller than 10000001000000". OK, I don't see how this is true. Please, explain. Show me how the proof can be modified.

Comment: You already did

Comment: @user389973 Again, you are making a claim I don't agree with, so it's again up to you to provide proof.

Comment: You already did

Comment: @user389973 You aren't really here to learn, are you?

Comment: You clearly aren't.

Answer (score 2):

There are a considerable number of problems. First, you've omitted the base case; induction can only work if the claim holds of the starting point (usually $0$). Second, steps (2) and (3) have no content; $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ simply have values, no solving is required. Third, step (4) draws a conclusion that isn't there; why do you think that $f(n)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$? Or that $f(n+1)$ is?

Comment: The base can be anything. For example, 1.